# Parsing python list of dates into a pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, datetime, python-3.6

need some help/advise how to wrangling dates into a Pandas DataFrame. I have Python list looking like this:

```
['',
 '20180715:1700-20180716:1600',
 '20180716:1700-20180717:1600',
 '20180717:1700-20180718:1600',
 '20180718:1700-20180719:1600',
 '20180719:1700-20180720:1600',
 '20180721:CLOSED',
 '20180722:1700-20180723:1600',
 '20180723:1700-20180724:1600',
 '20180724:1700-20180725:1600',
 '20180725:1700-20180726:1600',
 '20180726:1700-20180727:1600',
 '20180728:CLOSED']
```

Is there an easy way to transform this into a Pandas DataFrame with two columns (start time and end time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample:

```
L = ['',
 '20180715:1700-20180716:1600',
 '20180716:1700-20180717:1600',
 '20180717:1700-20180718:1600',
 '20180718:1700-20180719:1600',
 '20180719:1700-20180720:1600',
 '20180721:CLOSED',
 '20180722:1700-20180723:1600',
 '20180723:1700-20180724:1600',
 '20180724:1700-20180725:1600',
 '20180725:1700-20180726:1600',
 '20180726:1700-20180727:1600',
 '20180728:CLOSED']
```

I think best here is use list comprehension with split by separator and filter out values with no splitter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split('-') for x in L if '-' in x], columns=['start','end'])
print (df)
           start            end
0  20180715:1700  20180716:1600
1  20180716:1700  20180717:1600
2  20180717:1700  20180718:1600
3  20180718:1700  20180719:1600
4  20180719:1700  20180720:1600
5  20180722:1700  20180723:1600
6  20180723:1700  20180724:1600
7  20180724:1700  20180725:1600
8  20180725:1700  20180726:1600
9  20180726:1700  20180727:1600
```

Pandas solution is also possible, especially if need process `Series` - here is used [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
s = pd.Series(L)

df = s.str.split('-', expand=True).dropna(subset=[1])
df.columns = ['start','end']
print (df)
            start            end
1   20180715:1700  20180716:1600
2   20180716:1700  20180717:1600
3   20180717:1700  20180718:1600
4   20180718:1700  20180719:1600
5   20180719:1700  20180720:1600
7   20180722:1700  20180723:1600
8   20180723:1700  20180724:1600
9   20180724:1700  20180725:1600
10  20180725:1700  20180726:1600
11  20180726:1700  20180727:1600
```

Comment: both are working but they are obviously not datetime yet. use apply to transform them?

Comment: @steff - Hmm, so list is different? There are some nested values?

Comment: i have a function parsing it into the right shape but its quite specific for this case. can simply apply that

Comment: @steff - So need convert output columns to datetimes as last step?

Comment: @steff - So need `df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d:%H%M'))` ?